# iOS share extension exception - items configuration

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios8-share-extension

I'm having troubles implementing the share extension in an application. I'm using swift 3, xcode8.

```
override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
    // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
    let item = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem();
    item?.title = "Test";
    item?.value = "Value";
    item?.tapHandler = self.show;
    return [item]
}

func show() {
    print("TEST");
}
```

When I add that code to configure the items, I get the exception :

```
2016-09-19 09:22:20.623471 ARShareExtension[10583:675495] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue setChangeObserver:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17025af40'
```

I don't know what is wrong, I'm doing it as described in the apple developer site. I would appreciate if someone could help me :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but if anyone still has problems with this, `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem()` is now returning an `Optional` for some reason, but the return value is supposed to be an array of non-optional items, so you can do either

`let item = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem()!`

or

`guard let item = SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem() else { return nil }`